# linux prevent file descriptor from closing on program exit

Tags: c++, c, linux, file, unix

I have a peculiar use case where on linux when using uinput http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput, the process that creates the virtual input device, if it dies by default releases all open file descriptors.

In this case it also releases the created virtual input device and the device flat out disappears from /dev/input.

I am wondering if there is a simple solution to this problem, the most obvious being to not release the open file descriptor upon program termination. The more annoying one to spawn a proxy process to simply hold the FD.

Comment: All open file descriptors are closed when a program exits. Period.

Comment: As above.  But file descriptors will be inherited in the child process created by a fork.  And will remain open in the child when the parent exits.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the virtual device after the program that creates it exits? The program that creates it is the only one with the `fd` needed to inject events into the device (unless the fd is passed to another process). So if that goes away there can be no more events and hence no use for the virtual device.

Comment: Why exactly is /dev/input disappearing a problem in the first place?

Comment: /dev/uinput/event[n] disappearing is a problem because the virtual device gets passed to qemu via full input device passthrough introduced in qemu 2.5/2.6.  When the process that created the device crashes, say due to a bug in the code, the device disappears. After the crashed processes code gets fixed and it restarts, it cannot communicate with the qemu instance anymore, as the event[n] device is gone (requiring qemu guest teardown + relaunch to get a new uinput device back).  I thought once the device got passed through to qemu it would hold it from closing, not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going the proxy approach like so:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv) {
   create_uinput_device();
   print_eventn();
   set_argv0_eventn();
   if (fork()) {
       return;
   } else {
       //hold the uinput fd
       while(1) { sleep(1000); }
   }
}
```

This way when we cat /proc/[p]/cmdline we can easily find the /dev/input/event[n] and which pid is currently holding it. We can memcpy the new cmdline to argv0. So this is kind of a hack around this.

Also conveniently when we run this program we return right away with the /dev/input/event[n] device we need to forward to qemu; due to the print.

To truly fix this someone needs to merge into qemu changes so qemu itself creates the virtual input device, this is quite complex due to the vast amount of options that can be passed. Regardless once figured out, the virtual input device created by uinput will live as long as the qemu instance.